# Simulate and Plot each Vout given 40 Resistances and a 4 Resistor Network

Tags: ltspice

I have a list of 40 different resistances and a 4 resistor network with which to substitute these values into. I want to be able generate values of Vout(Vadc) given every permutation of 40 different values in a 4 resistor network with ease.

[image]

[image]

```
.step param Rx list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40

.param R1 table(Rx,1,4.7,2,10,3,33,4,49.9,5,68,6,75,7,120,8,470,9,750,10,1k,11,1.2k,
12,1.21k,12,1.5k,13,2.7k,14,3.23k,15,4.53k,16,4.7k,17,4.99k,18,5.6k,19,6.49,
20,6.8k,21,8.2k,22,9.1k,23,10k,24,10.2k,25,12.1k,26,13k,27,16.2k,28,18k,29,36k,
30,36.5k,31,47k,32,51k,33,82k,34,100k,35,150k,36,169k,37,330k,38,390k,39,510k,40,1000k,41,3600k)

.param R2 table(Rx,1,4.7,2,10,3,33,4,49.9,5,68,6,75,7,120,8,470,9,750,10,1k,11,1.2k,
12,1.21k,12,1.5k,13,2.7k,14,3.23k,15,4.53k,16,4.7k,17,4.99k,18,5.6k,19,6.49,
20,6.8k,21,8.2k,22,9.1k,23,10k,24,10.2k,25,12.1k,26,13k,27,16.2k,28,18k,29,36k,
30,36.5k,31,47k,32,51k,33,82k,34,100k,35,150k,36,169k,37,330k,38,390k,39,510k,40,1000k,41,3600k)

.param R3 table(Rx,1,4.7,2,10,3,33,4,49.9,5,68,6,75,7,120,8,470,9,750,10,1k,11,1.2k,
12,1.21k,12,1.5k,13,2.7k,14,3.23k,15,4.53k,16,4.7k,17,4.99k,18,5.6k,19,6.49,
20,6.8k,21,8.2k,22,9.1k,23,10k,24,10.2k,25,12.1k,26,13k,27,16.2k,28,18k,29,36k,
30,36.5k,31,47k,32,51k,33,82k,34,100k,35,150k,36,169k,37,330k,38,390k,39,510k,40,1000k,41,3600k)

.param R11 table(Rx,1,4.7,2,10,3,33,4,49.9,5,68,6,75,7,120,8,470,9,750,10,1k,11,1.2k,
12,1.21k,12,1.5k,13,2.7k,14,3.23k,15,4.53k,16,4.7k,17,4.99k,18,5.6k,19,6.49,
20,6.8k,21,8.2k,22,9.1k,23,10k,24,10.2k,25,12.1k,26,13k,27,16.2k,28,18k,29,36k,
30,36.5k,31,47k,32,51k,33,82k,34,100k,35,150k,36,169k,37,330k,38,390k,39,510k,40,1000k,41,3600k)
```

I haven't been given a target voltage value that is ideal but I just want to have the simulation ready so that I can readily select resistor values given the when they tell me what the target Vout(Vadc) is.

This only displays values when all resistors have the same resistance. Not sure how to bring about each permutation other than adjust the code by hand. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to run \$40^4\$ simulations? 2,560,000 simulations?

Comment: This is unwieldy at best for LTSpice. Solve the network algebraically, and then  consider what patterns or symmetries you find. Even if you find no symmetries, you will have a simpler algebraic expression which can be computed far more rapidly for 2.56 million iterations using a suitable program.

Comment: Or at least adjust the dot commands to simulate a subset of resistances.

Comment: See [This page](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-worst-case-circuit-analysis-with-minimal-simulations-runs.html) where they vary multiple resistors at once. Finding [Process corners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_corners) is frequently needed in electronics. SPICE should have an option for that. However, I agree with the other commenters that,finding and algebraic expression is better for your specific example.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It's 40!/(40-4)!=2,193,360 permutations. But it's still a LOT!! (And it's 91,390 combinations if that's all the OP wants -- but it sounds like the OP wants permutations.)

Comment: @jonk The OP said they want **every** permutation of the 40 values. They complain that they are now getting **only** the case where all resistors are the same, but I don't see any language that says that they only care about cases where the four resistors have different values.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson See: "every permutation of 40 *different* values". That's where I got it.

Comment: @jonk Fair enough, I see your point.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Of course, whether your reading or mine, your basic point still remains. ;)

Comment: I need combinations not permutations. Sorry about that.